# Bot is removing all songs from queue instead of 1 when song stops

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to make a queue and make my bot play it until bot has no songs in queue but istead of removing 1 song from queue (song that was played) - queue clears fully!
Code:

```js
  player.on(AudioPlayerStatus.Idle, () => {
    queue.splice(0, 1);
    if(!queue[0]) return;
    resource = createAudioResource(join('./music/', `${queue[0].toLowerCase()}.mp3`));
    player.play(resource);
  });
```

I tried console logging every step (except `if(!queue[0]) return`) and got this:

```
song1,song2,song3
song2,song3
song2,song3
song2,song3
song3
song3
song3
<empty>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Update 1: It removes all the songs one by one, start playing last song I added and right after it - removes last song from array

Comment: Except the fact using `Array.shift` will optimise your code, I don't see errors in the code. But there might be errors playing the resource. You can add the following lines to catch and log the errors on loading and paying a resource `player.on('error', error => {
 console.error('Error:', error.message, 'with track', error.resource.metadata.title);
});`

Comment: @Reflective yea, `queue.shift()` does not help at all and I get no errors

Comment: I know it won't help, it's just the better approach as you have the value shifted into a variable. Just better practice. It's not very clear as timing how the problem appears. If you do a video or post a timing diagram from execution it might become more clear what might be the problem.